# Clarification regarding Prime theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This is one theorem which I came across the book:

> For every positive integer $n$, there is a sequence of $n$ consecutive positive integers containing no primes.

Is this theorem valid ?

Because if $n = 2$, then its next consecutive integer $3$ itself is prime.

Comment: Instead of explaining why your remark is wrong, I'll explain why the theorem is true for $n=2$ and hopefully this will suffice to get rid of some confusion. Consider the finite sequence $\langle 8,9\rangle$. It is a sequence of $2$ consecutive positive integers containing no prime numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think you're proving with your example of $\;n=2\;$ , but the theorem says that if, for example, $\;n=2\;$ , then there exist two consecutive integers none of which is prime.

Comment: @GitGud Ah thanks, I get this now. Can you post that as an answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to develop such a sequence. However, it may not be the first such sequence. If you want to find a sequence of $n$ consecutive composite numbers, the classical way is to first calculate $(n+1)!$. Then the sequence:
$$
\{(n+1)!+2,(n+1)!+3,...,(n+1)!+(n+1)\}
$$
Is a sequence of n consecutive composite numbers. The first is divisible by 2 as both $(n+1)!$ and $2$ will be divisible, and so on for all these $n$ numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that it does *not* say where the span of consecutive numbers has to start, nor does it say that it is a span of *exactly* $n$ composite numbers.

So, for $n = 2$, we want to find two consecutive composite numbers. 8 and 9 fit the bill, so that works for us. Now, 10 is also composite, so that helps us out for $n = 3$. The span of consecutive numbers from 24 to 28 helps us for $n = 4$ or 5. In fact, take a look at Sloane's [A030296](https://oeis.org/A030296). (Sloane's OEIS is an indispensable resource for many number theory inquiries).

Now, if you don't care about finding the *first* span of at least $n$ consecutive composite numbers, you can just do $(n + 1)!$ Then every number from $(n + 1)! + 2$ to $(n + 1)! + n$ is guaranteed to be composite. In some cases, you'll also get $(n + 1)! + 1$ is composite, too (see Wilson's theorem), and if $n$ is odd, then $(n + 1)! + n + 1$ is composite as well.